# What is the purpose of outer and inner function parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, currying

In the following code:

```
def product(f: Int => Int)(a:Int, b:Int): Int =
   if (a > b) 1
   else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
```

The parameters `a` and `b` are passed to the inner function, but you could write exactly the same function definition like so:

```
def product(f: Int => Int, a:Int, b:Int): Int =
  if (a > b) 1
  else f(a) * product(f, a + 1, b)
```

So what is the purpose of separating the parameters? In other words, why do this:

```
(f: Int => Int)(a:Int, b:Int)
```

when you can more clearly write:

```
(f: Int => Int, a:Int, b:Int)
```

Comment: In fact they are not "outer" or "inner", there can be arbitrary number of parameter lists :) `f(a: Int)(b: Double)(c: String)(d: Long)` is absoletely legal.

Answer (score 3):

Another feature of multiple parameters lists is partial application:

```
def sum3(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int): Int = a + b + c

val g: Int => Int => Int = sum3(10) _
val h: Int => Int        = g(20)
val r: Int               = h(30)    // 10 + 20 + 30 = 60
```

You can partially apply a function and obtain another function which is equivalent to the original one but with one of the arguments fixed. `_` after `sum3(10)` is needed because `sum3` is a method, not a function, and `_` converts methods to functions.

This is very useful when you are using higher-order functions:

```
def adder(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y

Seq(1, 2, 3, 4) map adder(10)  // Seq(11, 12, 13, 14)
```

When partially applied method/function is used as an argument of a higher-order call, `_` is not needed, and the syntax becomes very succinct.

Comment: Thanks - should your `f(10)` call above be `sum3(10)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Another use case of this feature  is that if you want to create a control structure that looks like it's built into Scala programming language itself.

For example, I could write an control structure named `times` which help me execute the code block exactly `n` times by the following method definition:

```
// since block is call by name, it will not be evaluate when you call it.
def times(n: Int)(block: => Any): Unit = {  
  for (i <- 0 until n) {
    block // evaluate(execute) block
  }
}

// Now I can use the times method like a control structure
times(5) { 
  println("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: I love this feature in scala.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether there is implicit parameter (which can't be properly mixed with plain ones)...

```scala
def foo(i: Int)(implicit p: P): Foo
```

... and the way you want to call it ...

```scala
def foo1(a: Int)(b: Int => Boolean): Boolean
foo1(9) { i => false }

def foo2(a: Int, b: Int => Boolean): Boolean
foo2(9, { i => false })
```